# correct idiom for if you were me

Tags: idioms, american-english, british-english, quotes, proverbs

I am looking for an idiom that can be used for this like "if you were me you would have done the same thing "
 OR something like empathy , think from my sight, is there any idiom for such scenerio?
I tried to figure out but couldn't find that

I found something like, see through my eyes, but thats not appealing at all.
I thought of "be at my place" but I dont think it gives correct meaning

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can say:  *If you were in my shoes*, would you do the same thing?

Comment: I found that earlier but its not appealing at all, is there any other option?

Comment: Must it be an idiom?  If you were in my position..

Comment: idiom because just need a small sentence that holds a big meaning, what about see through my eyes any idiom for that

Comment: @user1765876 'Appealing' is surely used to describe a subjectively-defined notion. Let's see how many votes Josh gets.

Comment: Similar:"(you should) walk a mile in my shoes". This and Josh's variant are probably the best English has!

Answer (score 1):

*In my place you would have done the same thing.*

Answer (score -1):

if the shoe were on the other foot

Comment: No, that has a completely different meaning, not that you and he are exchanging places/experiences, but that there is (or was) a misfit (i.e., the left shoe was on the right foot, which isn't a good fit).